# Explaining in an easy way why the initial object is the colimit of the empty diagram?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I have read yesterday the following statement:

An initial object when it exists is the colimit of the empty diagram. A terminal object when it exists is the limit of the empty diagram.

And I found some justification of the second statement here:

[What means an empty diagram?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301166/what-means-an-empty-diagram) but still the justification is not very clear to me, I am wondering if someone can explain this to me in a simpler way please?

Comment: An object $c$ serves a colimit of diagram $D$ if for all object $a$ a unique arrow $c\to a$ exists "such that...(conditions concerning diagram $D$)". Now if diagram $D$ is empty then the part "such that...(conditions concerning diagram $D$)" is empty and falls away. What remains is exactly the statement that $c$ is an initial object.

Comment: @drhab that is incredibly clear, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A precise way to understand this is as follows :

Note that for a diagram $D : I \rightarrow C$, its colimit, if it exists, represents the functor $Cocone(D,-) : C \rightarrow Set$ which maps an object $c \in C$ onto the set of cocones on $D$ with vertex $c$. In other words,
$$Cocone(D,c) \cong C(colim\text{ }D, c)$$ naturally in $c \in C$.

In the specific case that the shape category $I = \emptyset$, $Cocone(D,c)$ (which is the set of all natural transformations $D \rightarrow \Delta_c$) is a singleton set (namely, the natural transformation with no components).

Thus, for any object $c$, $C(colim\text{ }D, c) \cong Cocone(D,c)$ is a singleton set. Thus, $Colim\text{ }D$ is an initial object.